# Menu dropdown doesn't collapse on mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm building a site, located [here](http://staging.lifestylerevolutionstx.com/), in Foundation 3 and I noticed that the dropdowns for the top-bar menu only collapse when you click somewhere in the body or move the cursor to another place in the menu. If you exit the menu by moving the cursor into the body from a dropdown, it just stays open. Is there a way to make it collapse on mouse out?

Unfortunately I do not know what specific code in the framework controls the functionality of the dropdown collapse. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

If you place the following code right at the bottom of your page, just before the `</body>` tag

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {

             $('.has-dropdown').on('mouseout', function () {
                 $(this).find('.dropdown').hide()
             });

             $('.has-dropdown').on('mousemove', function () {
                 $(this).find('.dropdown').show()
             });
         });
     </script>
```

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your help! I don't have a ton of background in Javascript, so I'm not sure where to insert your code. I put it at the bottom of the JS file that controls the menu bar, foundation.topbar.js, to no affect. Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: hi Brandon, i've updated the code so you can just drop it in your page.

Comment: I put your code in the head tag but it still isn't working. Could there be other code that is overriding it? I included it as follows:`<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         $('.has-dropdown').on('mouseout', function () {
             $(this).find('.dropdown').hide()
         });

         $('.has-dropdown').on('mousemove', function () {
             $(this).find('.dropdown').show()
         });
     });
 </script> `

Comment: Hi Brandon, if you place the code right at the bottom of your page, just before the </body> tag, after everything else in the <body> tag

Comment: Worked like a charm in Chrome, but in Firefox the dropdown is collapsing when the cursor leaves the parent menu item. Any idea why?

Comment: Hey Sam, just double checking to see if you might have any idea why the dropdown collapses when mousing out of the parent menu item in Firefox. Any guidance would be much appreciated! Thank you!